# Guestbook application doesn't work. I used html, php, mysql, javascript. Can't add messages to the guestbook page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a simple application to make and i'm struggling to make it work.
It's a guestbook page which I have to make and it must have 3 fields:

1. Name
2. Email
3. Message box
4. A submit button.

All of the message must be at least 5 chars and at the push of the button, it must get under the message box.

For this, I created

I. Three files:

1.index.html - where is the main code in JS and also html

2.addcomment.php

3.guestbook.php

II. One Database (which I named it "db1")
The Problem is that when I click submit, instead of recording the comment underneath, the addcomment.php code appears in my html page. What could be the problem.

I won`t put the "head" part of the index.html page here because it's only JS which checks the fields to be correct. I'll put the "body" of the html page so you can tell me if something it's wrong:

```
//Update: 
<body>
<div id="wrapper"
 </div>
<div id="menu">
<hr/>
<ul id="mainMenu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="guestbook.php" id="active">Guestbook</a></li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</div>
<div id="content">
//finished update

<h2>Sign to the Guest Book </h2>
<form name="guest" method="post" action="addcomment.php" onsubmit="return Validate();">
<span>Name:</span>    <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
<span>Email:</span> <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
<p>Message:</p> <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50"> </textarea> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Sign this in the Book" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
 <div id="footer">
<hr/>
 <p>Thank you for the visit! </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the addcomment.php code which is called above:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$user="db1";
$pass="test123";
$dbname="db1"; 
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "<h1>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() ."</h1>";
}
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$sql="INSERT INTO db1(name,email,message) VALUES('$name','$email','$message')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else
    echo "Values stored to db!";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So. I installed XAMMP. and using xammp control panel I started the server Apache and MySql. Using that, I created a db using localhost/phpmyadmin which I named "db1". I gave the user and db the same name and I granted all acces for that user to my database.

Here is the SQL query I used for the table creation in phpmyadmin to my "db1":

```
CREATE TABLE db1(
id int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
name varchar(60) NOT NULL default ' ',
email varchar(60) NOT NULL default ' ',
message text NOT NULL,
Primary key(id)
);
```

Can you tell me why my page doesn't work? Why the messages doesn`t post? I simply don't get it and tried everything the past weekend.
Thanks a lot

**Update**: It worked. It seems that if we call it from the address bar and not from the folder with double click, it works. I just wrote in the address bar: localhost/guestbook, and it worked.
Here is my other file "guestbook.php" which I used to show on the index.html page the comments from the users:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; //Add your SQL Server host here
$user="db1"; //SQL Username
$pass="test123"; //SQL Password
$dbname="db1"; //SQL Database Name
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name,message FROM db1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
<h3><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3>
<p><?php echo $row['message']; ?></p>
<?php } 
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I also updated the html code above so you can see how I created the menu for guestbook list.

Comment: You getting any Errors?

Comment: Here is the problem/error: "The Problem is that when I click submit, instead of recording the comment underneath, the addcomment.php code appears in my html page. What could be the problem.". The issue is probably that you are accessing your file like 'C://xammp/html/asldkjasldjk' instead of doing through 'http://localhost/myproject/alksdjalksdj'

Comment: You/re right. I accesed it from C:\xampp\htdocs\guestbook, and simply opened index.html in Google Chrome, that`s why it didn`t work out. I also tried directly from address bar with "localhost/guestbook and it worked!! When I click submit I get the message: "Values Stored in Our Database". But still, they don`t post as comments underneath the message box... What could be the problem there? Thanks again

Comment: I solved it. just edited my question so you can see the last php code i added and called from index.html. Thanks a lot